# ¿Cómo poder integrar todos los registros varias tablas en una?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy creando una aplicación web, basada de un portal de usuarios.  Tengo un login para cada tipo de usuario dentro la aplicación. Pero me gustaría más poder hacer un solo login y de acuerdo a los datos que ingrese, inicie sesión como un tipo de usuario determinado. Esto consiste en por cada tipo de usuario se hace una consulta a esta tabla, es decir, si deseo ingresar como Profesor, hace consulta a la tabla Profesor.

Básicamente pido un consejo o ayuda de como poder relacionar todos los registros de estas tablas e integrarlas en una, y desde ahi hacer la consulta a la base de datos.

Podrá ser algún JOIN? La verdad no estoy seguro que método puedo usar para solucionar este nuevo requerimiento.

Saludos Muchas Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Es un error muy común en los principiante y yo también lo hice, aquí tengo un modelo que me permite integral el uso de roles y permisos para la integración de la aplicación, en la cual dependiendo el tipo de roles se le dar los permisos, con este modelo se puede identificar los roles y los permisos que tiene cada usuario, otrar cosa seria traer los datos de un join le sugiero que vea este video de como traer los datos de una forma mucho mas facil https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijGHzXu_RkU

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es, como tienes una tabla de `usuarios` y otra tabla de `tipos de usuarios`, relacionarlas con un `id`, quedaría de la siguiente manera

```
**Tabla Usuarios:**
id_usuario
Nombre
Apellido
Telefono
usuario
password
id_tipo_usuario

**Tabla Tipo_Usuario:**
id_tipo_usuario
permisos
```

Luego al realizar el `select` en el `Login` tendrías algo como esto:

```
select u.usuario, u.password, tu.permisos from Usuarios u JOIN Tipo_Usuario tu ON u.id_tipo_usuario = tu.id_tipo_usuario where u.usuario = :var_usuario and u.password = :var_password
```

Utilizo `:var_usuario` y `:var_password` porque imagino que utilizas **PDO MySQL**

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

pues utiliza dos tablas, una para usuarios y otra para tipo de usuarios, en la tabla usuarios guardas id, nombre, etc.... y en la tabla tipo_usuario guardas id(para la tabla), id_usuario(FK a usuarios), tipo_usuario(Administrador, profesor, etc) y puedes hacer una mas para permisos_modulos donde agregues los modulos creados y los usuarios que tendran permiso a dichos modulos, mira te pongo un mini ejemplo de la estructura, cada tabla puedes meterle los datos que necesites, el resto se hace en codigo mediante sesiones

[image: Diagrama simple]